# How to create a box plot for a grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
Datetime          Field1  Field2
2018-10-01 10:00  10      13
2018-10-01 11:00  18      14
2018-10-01 12:00  11      16
2018-10-01 13:00  12      15
2018-10-01 14:00  13      15
2018-10-01 15:00  11      11
2018-10-02 10:00  14      15
2018-10-02 11:00  15      15
2018-10-02 12:00  12      12
2018-10-02 13:00  11      15
2018-10-02 14:00  10      13
2018-10-02 15:00  10      15
2018-10-03 10:00  15      11
2018-10-03 11:00  13      12
2018-10-03 12:00  11      12
2018-10-03 13:00  11      11
2018-10-03 14:00  11      13
2018-10-03 15:00  12      15
```

I need to create a box plot to show how the values of `Field2` are distributed when grouped by `Field1`. The result should be conceptually similar to this plot, where `X` should be `Field1` and `Y` should be `Field2`):

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
df = df.set_index("Field1")
grouped = df.groupby(level="Field1")
grouped.boxplot(rot=45, fontsize=12, figsize=(10,5))
```

But this code gets stuck and does not provide any results.

Comment: Are you using the latest pandas and matplotlib versions?

Comment: If you're fine using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) you can do: `sns.boxplot(data=df, x="Field1", y="Field2")`

Comment: The easiest way to create such a plot is via seaborn's `sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Field1', y='Field2')` on the original dataframe (without the `set_index`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking you should reshape your dataframe then plot:

```py
df_ = df.pivot(columns=["Field1"], values=["Field2"])
df_.columns = df_.columns.droplevel(0)
df_.boxplot(rot=45, fontsize=12, figsize=(10,5))
```

Which outputs:

[image]

---

Alternatively, using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html), which requires no pivoting/grouping by you:

```py
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="Field1", y="Field2")
```

[image]

Comment: I get `KeyError: 'Level Field1 not found'`

Comment: For which example?

Comment: For the 1st one.

Comment: It won't work if you've already set the index to `Field1`. That should be a Series, not the index.